# Showing that a family of random variables is not independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm stuck on a problem from Axler's *Measure, Integration, & Real Analysis*. It reads

> Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $(-\pi,\pi]$ and $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $((-\pi,\pi],\mathcal{B})$ divided by $2 \pi$. Let $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}}$ be the family of functions from $(-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$e_k= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin(kt) & k>0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(kt) & k<0 \end{cases}.$$
> We are then asked to show that:

1. $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}}$ is not an independent family of random variables.
2. $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}}$ is an identically distributed family.

The second part was not so difficult, but I am having trouble with the first part.
Axler's definition for families of independent random variables are as follows:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. A family $\{X_k\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is independent if the family of events $\{X_k \in U_k\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ is independent for all families of Borel sets $\{U_k\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Here $\{X_k \in U_k\}$ is short for the set $\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X_k(\omega) \in U_k\}$.

From this it seems that it would be wise to find an example of a Borel family $\{U_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{ e_k \in U_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}}$ is not an independent family of events, but I cannot seem to find such an example. So far I've tried looking at the family formed by $U_{k<0} = (\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k})$ and $U_{k>0} = (-\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k})$, but this did not lead anywhere. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $e_1^{-1} (0,\epsilon)$ and $e_{-1}^{-1} (0,\epsilon)$. Observe that $e_1^{2}+e_{-1}^{2}=1/\pi$. This implies that the events are disjoint for $\epsilon$ small enough. But each of the events has probability $>0$ so they are not independent.